# Append text to start of matched pattern in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file called ${sysmain_content}. I am trying to place this just before the pattern [DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION] in the file /var/tmp/sym_links.ini.$$.

So i want [DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION] to appear at the end rather than the start of the replaced string in the file below.

`

```
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
; DWH MAIN DBSPACE information
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DWH_SYSTEM_MAIN]
DWH_SYSTEM_MAIN_1
DWH_SYSTEM_MAIN_2

[DWH_SYSTEM_MAIN_1]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/iq_system_main.iq
Lun_ID=
Type=fs
Size=30166
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION]
```

My attempt below using sed and r does the opposite in that its prints the file content first.

```
sed "/^\[DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION\]$/r ${sysmain_content}" /var/tmp/sym_links.ini.$$ > /var/tmp/sym_links.ini.$$.tmp1
```

Comment: Not sure I get you right. You want to move the whole section "[DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION]" within the file to it's very end, right? So the line [DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION] and all following lines up to (but excluding) the next section that begins with [... right?

Comment: Hi. No i want to place the content of a separate file into the current file, but have the [DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION] to appear immediately after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\[DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION\]$/e cat '"${sysmain_content}"'' file
```

Use the evaluate command and `cat` the file before printing the output line.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sed -e your_file_name.ini '
/\[DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION\]/ {
    r new_section.ini
    a\
\n[DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION]
    d
}
'
```

The file with the section(s) you want to insert is named new_section.ini in the example above. You might want to rename it. Then it uses the r command, as in your basis to insert this file, supresses the normal output of the [DWH_DBSPACES_LOCATION] and appends it after inserting the file content using the a-command.